# Оставить строки определённой длинны

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Добрый день, имеется большой файл со строками, нужно удалить строки короче 6 символов и длиннее 10. Как это можно сделать в линуксе ?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'length($0)>6 && length($0)<10 ' filename
```

или

```
egrep "^.{6,10}$" filename
```

Comment: второй вариант вы явно не проверяли.

Comment: 1. `... файл > файл` - бессмысленная конструкция. 2. опция `-v` служит для инвертирования условия.

Comment: Я попробывал все варианты, вариант с грепом должен звучать как 5,11 НО ниодин вариант не справился на все 100% - так как всётаки попадаются строки с 4 и 5 символами

Comment: @3amunyk, *строки с 4 и 5 символами* - символы, небось, многобайтные? а какую локаль передаёте программе?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, прочитайте, пожалуйста, вопрос ещё раз. `$ echo 1 | фильтр` **должно** вывести пустую строку.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо. я понял и исправил

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, осталось совсем немного. перед выполнением `программа аргументы > файл` оболочка **сначала** очистит файл, а потом уже запустит программу.

Comment: Размер файла 1.5ГБ локаль ? по идее утф8

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не вводите людей в заблуждение, файл не очищается, а пересоздаётся.

Answer (score 2):

для программы *gnu/sed*:

```
$ sed -rni '/^.{6,10}$/p' файл
```